# How to prevent/control Moose use of confess

Tags: perl, moose

Moose uses `Carp::confess` profusely. According to the [Carp module documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Carp) you can tell Carp to reduce the amount of cruft being printed out or which packages to skip as "internals" among other useful global options. But apparently Moose totally ignores Carp's global settings.

For instance, here the global `$Carp::MaxArgNums = -1` should tell Carp to hide the function arguments with an ellipsis `...`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Carp;
$Carp::MaxArgNums = -1;

package Foo {
    use Moose;
    has bar => qw(is rw required 1);
}

package Quz {
    sub main {
        Carp::cluck('just warning');
        Foo->new({},{});
    }
}

Quz->main({},{});
```

It works for the plain `cluck` warning but not for the Moose `confess`.

```
just warning at moose-carp.pl line 14.
    Quz::main(...) called at moose-carp.pl line 19
Attribute (bar) is required at /Users/rod/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/lib/site_perl/5.26.1/darwin-2level/Moose/Object.pm line 24
    Moose::Object::new('Foo', 'HASH(0x7f882d885060)', 'HASH(0x7f882d648288)') called at moose-carp.pl line 15
    Quz::main('Quz', 'HASH(0x7f882d003280)', 'HASH(0x7f882d00bc18)') called at moose-carp.pl line 19
```

The same applies to the rest of Carp's global options. How can I prevent or control Moose use of `Carp::confess`?

Comment: It seems `Moose` does not use `Carp::confess`. Looks like it simply calls `die`, see [`Moose::Util` line #48](https://metacpan.org/release/Moose/source/lib/Moose/Util.pm#L48)

Comment: The exception string is built using `Devel::StackTrace`, see [`Moose::Exception::_build_trace`](https://metacpan.org/source/ETHER/Moose-2.2011/lib/Moose/Exception.pm#L31)

Comment: ok, just saw that. Even though `use Moose qw(confess)` exports `Carp::confess` for your peruse, Moose itself uses `Devel::StackTrace`. Go figure...